# Native SQL to get data into one row

Tags: sql, native, metabase

Below is the code I am using to get price to show under description of charge code... I tried to use group concat by that pulled everything into one row.... as with image below

the way they have the table set up surcharge description is in a column so if a rate has 3 surcharges it has 3 rows, what I was trying to do is to roll these up so surcharges show as their own headers and all charges in one row

[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWtGG.png)

```
     SELECT
q.orgId AS carrier_org_id,
originDoorCity AS origin,
source AS port_of_loading,
destination AS port_of_destination,
destinationDoorCity AS destination,
qc.containerType AS equipment_type,
-- group_concat(s.description) as 'combined description',

if (s.description in ('Base Rate'), c.CODE, null) as 'Frt CUR',
if (s.description in ('Base Rate'), price, null) as 'Ocean Rate',
if (s.description in ('Bunker Adjustment Factor','BAF','Bunker Surcharges','Bunker Adjustment Factor (BAF)','Bunker Adjustment Fee','Bunker Surcharge'), price, null) as 'Bunker',
if (s.description in ('Terminal Handling Service- Origin','Origin Terminal Handling Charge','Terminal Handling Charge - Origin','Terminal Handling Service'), c.CODE, null) as 'OTHC CUR',
if (s.description in ('Terminal Handling Service- Origin','Origin Terminal Handling Charge','Terminal Handling Charge - Origin','Terminal Handling Service'), price, null) as 'Origin Terminal Handling',
if (s.description in ('International Ship & Port Facility Security'), c.CODE, null) as 'SEC CUR',
if (s.description in ('International Ship & Port Facility Security'), price, null) as 'Port Security',
if (s.description in ('Documentation Fee- Origin','Origin Document Fee','Origin Documentation Fee','Documentation Fee','Orgin Documentation Fee'), c.CODE, null) as 'DocFee CUR',
if (s.description in ('Documentation Fee- Origin','Origin Document Fee','Origin Documentation Fee','Documentation Fee','Orgin Documentation Fee'), price, null) as 'Origin Doc Fee',
if (s.description in ('DG Surcharge','Hazardous Fee','Dangerous Goods','Hazardous Surcharge','Haz Surcharge','Hazardous Additional Charge (HAZ)'), c.CODE, null) as 'Haz CUR',
if (s.description in ('DG Surcharge','Hazardous Fee','Dangerous Goods','Hazardous Surcharge','Haz Surcharge','Hazardous Additional Charge (HAZ)'), price, null) as 'Haz Surcharge',

qc.commodityType AS commodity_type,
validityStartDate AS valid_from,
validityDate AS valid_until,
buyer.id AS buyer_org_id,
detentionDaysOrigin AS detention_days_origin,
detentionDaysDestination AS detention_days_destination,
buyerContractId AS buyer_contract_id,

routedVia,
buyer.NAME AS buyerName,
carrierCode,
rateType,
q.sourceRateCardId
FROM
QuoteSurcharge qs
JOIN Currency c ON qs.currencyId = c.id
JOIN Surcharge s ON qs.surchargeId = s.id
JOIN Quote q ON qs.quoteId = q.id
JOIN QuoteCriteria qc ON q.quoteCriteriaId = qc.id
JOIN Org buyer ON q.buyerOrgId = buyer.id
LEFT JOIN CommodityTypeResponse cr ON qc.commodityResponseId = cr.id
WHERE
validityDate >= now()
AND s.archived != TRUE
AND q.archived != TRUE
AND rateType = 'tendered'
AND buyer.NAME != 'Haven Markets Pte. Ltd. (For Customer Test)'
AND buyer.NAME LIKE CONCAT( '%',{{buyerName}}, '%' )
AND qc.orderId IS NULL

ORDER BY
buyerName,
carrier_org_id,
valid_until,
port_of_loading,
port_of_destination,
equipment_type,
description,
price;
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `IF` in "SQL"). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: group_concat is a MySQL function and its use in the question does not fit the requirement - The If statements are appropriate - but they need to be inside a "MAX() function) - which themselves will need an aggregator - which will be problem for performance in the current form as so many columns to group by upon - A subquery / correlated query with just three columns is recommended - s.description, c.Code, and "Price" to be joined into the main body of the query - -- Important - which table is "price" stored?

Comment: unfortunately Price is stored in this table... what I could do is create 2 sub tables then join them... yeah I was going to use the max function then thought better of it